# How do I resolve the error I get during the Full-Text search process?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to do it through sql server in my C# application. I am using the code below. When I search, I get this error.

```
string keyword = txtDetaylıArama.Text;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_KasaFişi Where Contains (Anahtar, '"+ txtDetaylıArama.Text +"') ", mycon);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
dgvDetaylı.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Error: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' türünde bir yakalanamayan özel durum, System.Data.dll öğesinde oluştu
Syntax error near 'Kuş' in the full-text search condition ' Çini Kuş'.

Comment: Hello, most users here don't speak turkish. Please provide the error message in english. I think the error has noting to do with C# (It definately has nothing to do with WPF). Have you tried to execute the statement directly in the Database? Also what is the content of `txtDetaylıArama.Text`?

Comment: Learn to **parametrise**; it's 2021 there is no excuse to be injecting at this time. Learn from the mistakes of others over the last 3 decades. Your SQL is dangerous. I don't know what the error says, so I have no idea what the problem is, but I would not be surprised that parametrising the query could likely fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Test following code

```
string SQL = "Select * from tbl_KasaFişi Where Contains(Anahtar, @DetaylıArama)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mycon))
{
   using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = SQL;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@DetaylıArama", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtDetaylıArama.Text;
       sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sda.Fill(dt);
       dgvDetaylı.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `LIKE` and `Contains` can give different results, based on the input. So without more information it is impossible for us to know if this will do what the OP wants. Also you should add the search condition as a parameter to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: This query is dangerous and should not be used.

Comment: You also need `using` blocks in order to dispose your connection and adapter correctly